# How to get opennlp plugin for pycharm

Tags: python, plugins, opennlp

I have converted java codes to python but some functionalities which can only be done through java are being used so opennlp package of java has to be used and i am not able to get any plugin in pycharm which would help me use opennlp

I didn't find any plugin or package to run opennlp in pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Like described [here](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/manual/opennlp.html#intro.cli) OpenNLP comes with a CLI.
To use OpenNLP from Python you can simply read/write some data files from python and call the CLI manually from the shell (i would recommend using jupyter notebooks for a worklflow like: Python(write) -> OpenNLP-CLI (read/write) -> Python(read)-> ... ).

A basic command to communicate by files has the following syntax:

```
opennlp ToolName lang-model-name.bin < input.txt > output.txt
```

where **lang-model-name.bin** is the language model-file you need to download before (see step 3 below). [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opennlp/opennlp_command_line_interface.htm) you find a useful and short tutorial describing the basic usage of the CLI.

Alternatively, e.g. if you want to avoid a workflow like the described one, you can consider writing a basic wrapper API to the CLI with a tool like [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

---

Setting up the CLI is very easy (like described in the [docs](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/manual/opennlp.html#intro.cli.setup)):

1. download [binary](https://opennlp.apache.org/download.html) and set %OPENNLP_HOME%\bin to Path
2. install Java and setup %JAVA_HOME%
3. You can download pre-defined models [here](https://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/)